# How to get the hash algorithm name using the OID in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography

I am trying to compute the hash of a byte array in Java. To get a MessageDigest instance, I need to inform the hash name, but I only have the hash OID. Is there another way to do this or an existing map from hash OID to hash names?

```
String oid = "1.2.3.4.5";
String digestAlgorithmName = getDigestAlgorithmName(oid);

MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestAlgorithmName);
byte[] actualHash = messageDigest.digest(new byte[] { 0x00 });
```

Comment: What kind of OID is that? ASN.1? Whose in charge of these OIDs?

Comment: It is a ASN.1 OID. These OIDs are the standardized ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer. The class org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedHelper from [Bouncy Castle Library](http://www.bouncycastle.org) has the mapping. I extracted the required snippet from there and copied here.

```
...
private static final Map     encryptionAlgs = new HashMap();
private static final Map     digestAlgs = new HashMap();

static
{
    encryptionAlgs.put(X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_dsa_with_sha1.getId(), "DSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_dsa.getId(), "DSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(OIWObjectIdentifiers.dsaWithSHA1.getId(), "DSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption.getId(), "RSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha1WithRSAEncryption.getId(), "RSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.teleTrusTRSAsignatureAlgorithm, "RSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_ea_rsa.getId(), "RSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(CMSSignedDataGenerator.ENCRYPTION_ECDSA, "ECDSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA2.getId(), "ECDSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA224.getId(), "ECDSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA256.getId(), "ECDSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA384.getId(), "ECDSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA512.getId(), "ECDSA");
    encryptionAlgs.put(CMSSignedDataGenerator.ENCRYPTION_RSA_PSS, "RSAandMGF1");
    encryptionAlgs.put(CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3410_94.getId(), "GOST3410");
    encryptionAlgs.put(CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3410_2001.getId(), "ECGOST3410");
    encryptionAlgs.put("1.3.6.1.4.1.5849.1.6.2", "ECGOST3410");
    encryptionAlgs.put("1.3.6.1.4.1.5849.1.1.5", "GOST3410");

    digestAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.md5.getId(), "MD5");
    digestAlgs.put(OIWObjectIdentifiers.idSHA1.getId(), "SHA1");
    digestAlgs.put(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha224.getId(), "SHA224");
    digestAlgs.put(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256.getId(), "SHA256");
    digestAlgs.put(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha384.getId(), "SHA384");
    digestAlgs.put(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha512.getId(), "SHA512");
    digestAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha1WithRSAEncryption.getId(), "SHA1");
    digestAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha224WithRSAEncryption.getId(), "SHA224");
    digestAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption.getId(), "SHA256");
    digestAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha384WithRSAEncryption.getId(), "SHA384");
    digestAlgs.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha512WithRSAEncryption.getId(), "SHA512");
    digestAlgs.put(TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.ripemd128.getId(), "RIPEMD128");
    digestAlgs.put(TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.ripemd160.getId(), "RIPEMD160");
    digestAlgs.put(TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.ripemd256.getId(), "RIPEMD256");
    digestAlgs.put(CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3411.getId(),  "GOST3411");
    digestAlgs.put("1.3.6.1.4.1.5849.1.2.1",  "GOST3411");
}

String getDigestAlgName(String digestAlgOID) {
    String algName = (String)digestAlgs.get(digestAlgOID);

    if (algName != null)
    {
        return algName;
    }

    return digestAlgOID;
}

String getEncryptionAlgName(String encryptionAlgOID) {
    String algName = (String)encryptionAlgs.get(encryptionAlgOID);

    if (algName != null)
    {
        return algName;
    }

    return encryptionAlgOID;
}

MessageDigest getDigestInstance(String algorithm, String provider) 
    throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    if (provider != null)
    {
        try
        {
            return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm, provider);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm); // try rolling back
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most of security providers (and BouncyCastle is one of them) defines not only single algorithm name, but also aliases, which include OID. Thus, it's possible to pass OID directly to JCA like this:

```
String oid = "1.3.14.3.2.26";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(
    oid, BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
String digestAlgorithmName = md.getAlgorithm();
```

`digestAlgorithmName` will be equal to `SHA-1` in the end. This doesn't work with SUN security provider.

Comment: Unfortunately, though JCE does also support OID aliases (at least in 1.8), `getAlgorithm()` would return the OID :)

Comment: Yes, SUN provider also got aliases specified for the algorithms, but it doesn't resolve algorithm name properly. So now it's required to use explicit name of security provider to get BouncyCastle's implementation of the `MessageDigest`.

Comment: For BouncyCastle I used: BCMessageDigest.getInstance(signer.getDigestAlgOID(), "BC").getAlgorithm();

Answer (score 2):

The class [org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedGenerator](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedGenerator.html) has constants for each of its supported algorithms. Its constants are public, so they're easier to use than package-only accessible CMSSignedHelper.

Comment: ´public´ is http://oid-info.com ?