# How to get an object identifier for a hash algorithm name in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have to perform conversions between cryptography algorithms names and their object identifiers (OIDs). I use Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) and Bouncy Castle as a security provider. Converting OIDs to textual names is fairly easy with JCA itself.

```
String oid = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.4";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(oid);
String digestAlgorithmName = md.getAlgorithm();
```

But how do I perform backward conversion from textual names to OIDs? There seems to be no way how to get aliases for algorithm name in JCA. Bouncy Castle 1.50 has maps, which connect algorithm names to OIDs, but all of them have restricted access.

Comment: An OID should map a OID to one specific algorithm. It's an ID, so that's probably what you expect. Unfortunately, OID's can be created by any recognized organization. Some of these algorithms have been established by multiple parties, resulting in multiple OID's pointing to the same algorithm. Personally I *would* hardcode the OID's if only to avoid multiple answers.

Comment: @owlstead: This is not the case at least with hashes, signatures and key factories. Otherwise security algorithms simply won't work. But on the other hand, this information is already encoded inside a security provider and available to JCA. It's just about finding a way to access it.

Comment: Basically you are arguing that security algorithms don't work if there are aliases, which is obviously bunk. Most protocols do directly define which OID's are required though, and *most* are defined by one organization. But to require a 1:1 relationship seems weird. Take encodings in Java. `"UTF-8"`, `"UTF8"` and `"Utf8"` all point to the same encoding. Doesn't encoding work? Same goes for cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: @owlstead: I understood your original comment as OIDs are not unique. Algorithm textual names are aliases and are already defined in security provider manifest to JCA. And as you are correctly pointed out there are more than one per OID, so hard-coding them in my code will result in need to maintain matching between my list and security provider list. That's why I want to delegate it to JCA or security provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few helper classes in the PKIX distribution which are specifically for dealing with this.

Have a look in org.bouncycastle.operator - DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder and DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder. There's also a few others in different places through the rest of the distribution.

Comment: Yes, http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/operator/DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.html#find%28java.lang.String%29 does what I actually need. This method is available in since BouncyCastle 1.47.

Comment: In 1.52, you would use `DefaultAlgorithmNameFinder` and `DefaultXXXXAlgorithmIdentifierFinder`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how OID can be extracted from a text description of a JCA service providing the desired algorithm. However, the solution is quite inelegant

```
DERObjectIdentifier oid = null;
String digestAlgorithmName = "SHA-224";
Provider provider = Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
Service service = provider.getService("MessageDigest", digestAlgorithmName);
if (service != null) {
    String string = service.toString();
    String array[] = string.split("\n");
    if (array.length > 1) {
        string = array[array.length - 1];
        array = string.split("[\\[\\]]");
        if (array.length > 2) {
            string = array[array.length - 2];
            array = string.split(", ");
            Arrays.sort(array);
            oid = new ASN1ObjectIdentifier(array[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Bouncy Castle's `CMSSignedHelper`. See [How to get the hash algorithm name using the OID in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379434/how-to-get-the-hash-algorithm-name-using-the-oid-in-java).

(I'm not going to repeat the answer because its on Stack Overflow's site).

Comment: Class CMSSignedHelper is package-private, so it can be accessed only from org.bouncycastle.cms package. BouncyCastle jars are signed, so new classes cannot be added to org.bouncycastle.cms package.

Comment: Thanks divanov. So I'm clear: David Reis's answer using `getEncryptionAlgName` and `getDigestAlgName` did not help you? (Even a `BiMap` did not help you?)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm searching for a solution, which won't require hard-coding values from BouncyCastle (or any other security provider) in my code.

Comment: In the past, I used the OID repository at http://www.oid-info.com. Submit a query like `http://oid-info.com/get/2.999`, and parse the `<title>` element. But you have to be online to do it. (That seems worse than creating a `BiMap` from `CMSSignedHelper`, but it might work for you since you seem to be stuck between a rock and a hard place).

Comment: By the way, you also have Peter Gutmann's database from his ASN.1 parser. Its not a security providers, and its fairly comprehensive. See `dumpasn1.cfg` at https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/dumpasn1.cfg.

Comment: What if you replace your current answer with these ideas?